# Java methods expecting parameters with multiple inheritance

Tags: java, syntax, multiple-inheritance

I don't know why I can't find an answer to this online.

I have classes that implement multiple methods and I would like to write methods to expect them. I don't know how to do it though or if it's even possible.

E.g:

```
public void yellAtPet(<? extends Pet implements YellableAt> arg) {
    arg.yellAt("Don't go there!"); 
    arg.pet("Good Boy");
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work fine as a generic method, without making your entire class generic:

```
public <T extends Pet & YellableAt> void yellAtPet(T arg) {
    arg.yellAt("Don't go there!"); 
    arg.pet("Good Boy");
}
```

Comment: @pavelrappo - I just tried it (with `Object` instead of `Pet` and `Runnable` instead of `YellableAt`). It compiles fine.

Answer (score 7):

Extends is used for both interfaces and parent classes.

If you want to inforce multiple extends you needs something like:

```
<T extends ClassA & InterfaceB>
```

To enforce this on a method, generify the class:

```
public class MyClass<T extends something & somethingelse>{
    public void doSomething(T arg)
    {
         //call methods defined by either interface
    }
}
```

Comment: Im sorry - I didnt realise that there was some arbitrary minimum number of methods per class.....

Comment: @user381105 That's standard OOP.