# Scala method expecting parameters template with multi inheritance

Tags: scala, templates, inheritance

I know that JAVA allows to make generic methods like (seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304763/java-methods-expecting-parameters-with-multiple-inheritance)):

```
public <T extends Pet & YellableAt> void yellAtPet(T arg) {
    arg.yellAt("Don't go there!"); 
    arg.pet("Good Boy");
}
```

I would like to be able to do the same in scala, eg :

```
 def addWorkers[T <: BuiltInfrastructure & TraitBuiltRecruter](bi : T, nbre : n){
   // do somthing
 }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def addWorkers[T <: BuiltInfrastructure with TraitBuiltRecruter](bi : T, nbre : n)
```

or even (since you don't need `T`):

```
def addWorkers(bi: BuiltInfrastructure with TraitBuiltRecruter, nbre : n)
```